# How to connect three pieces with screws?

Tags: screws

I'm designing a small greenhouse 60x40cm 60cm high.

Since I'm not even an amateur woodworker, I won't dare use anything but screws to connect the pieces.

Are pocket screws ok to connect pilar and two beams?

**Pilars are 3x3cm and others are 2x2cm. All pinus.**

Sketchup file and stl 3d model are [here](https://ufile.io/f/sjna2)

An image from the project:

[image: project]

I have basic tools like power drill, power screw driver, G clamps, chisels and a plane. Will have soon a ryoba saw and a work table (wx051 from worx).

Up to now I just screwed planks together to build plant stands on wheels.

The base will be on wheels. I live in an apartment and the greenhouse will stay at the balcony.

Comment: Welcome to WSE.  People will be better able to answer your question if you provide more information. A sketch or picture of what you plan would be helpful along with some sizes for the various members. BTW while pocket screws are possible, there are also other means of connecting things that do not require a great deal of skill.  IF you edit the scope of your question and let us know what tools you have available, you may get a wider range of answers.

Comment: Pocket screws make strong connections, but what are dimensions of wood? Will this be made from pressure treated softwood?

Comment: Thanks for your commens, I updated the question. I believe the wood is not treated, i'll use pinus, since it is the cheapest around here.

Comment: Now we know wood dimensions I think this will be ok, but do not expect much structural stability without joinery or other stiffening pieces such as diagonal bracing. Standing in place no problem, but you must design for when there are high winds.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're planning on setting this on as a base/foundation, but be aware that your 4 corner posts have their end-grain exposed to whatever that base is. Any moisture that collects on this base will wick directly up into that end-grain and speed the rotting of the posts. You would probably be better served by stopping the posts at the floor, _not_ notching the corners, and just screwing the wall frames down through the bottom plates and into the floor.

Answer (score 3):

One of the hardest skills to learn as a craftsperson is how to take your pretty plan and turn it into a real thing. And the single most important part of that is figuring out your order of operations. This is why it is important to consider the build process during planning, so you sweat the details like how it is assembled, and how the members meet and are fastened.

It makes no sense to me to try and balance three members going off at right angles to each other and trying to drive pocket screws at the same time. I'd recommend breaking the problem down into pieces.

For example, you have *basically* two face frames (or close enough for this conversation -- pedants will be ignored!). Assemble those, first. Your pocket screws will be on the inside mating the front and back members into their respective rectangular frames. Now what?

Well, we can see the problem that you've designed the sides to butt up against the frames. This isn't ideal if you want to manage racking, so maybe the sides are *also* a flat frame. Then you build up your box using four flat-assembled frames attached in some manner. Or maybe not. Maybe those long members connecting the front and rear frames are fine with a few pocket screws from below. Perhaps the box will stiffen up nicely once they are all in place and the notched bottom is in place.

But think about how you will assemble this thing from flat modules at the beginning so you minimize trying to coordinate three members in 3D space that would require some annoying clamping setup that you don't have the tools for anyway.

How to attach the roof part is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

> Are pocket screws ok to connect pilar and two beams?

Builders create multistory buildings using mostly nails as connectors. Given the size of your structure, I'm sure pocket screws will be more than adequate.

Your greenhouse will be much stronger if you take care to ensure the ends of the pieces are all cut square, so that the pocket screws can pull the joint tight. If you add rigid panels (like plexiglas or [twin-wall panels](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08KNMHWHS)) to the sides of your greenhouse, instead of [thin polyethylene film](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00BM8HHKK), that'll add a lot of strength to the structure.

Answer (score -1):

The structure you have drawn will be flimsy regardless of what kind of fasteners are used. I suggest reading books about framing and cabinetry to see how things are normally put together.

If this is a greenhouse with glass then you will need to design the windows and want that to be sturdy, so the windows are not falling out and breaking.

For your type of construction, one easy way to do a three-way joint is with a corner brace:

[image]

Comment: Even simple gussets (or cross-braces) would work, of course, without the need for special hardware.

Comment: FYI independent tests regularly show that pocket screws are roughly equivalent to M&Ts and sometimes they exceed their strength by a significant margin, >30% stronger.